# HTML input type date is sometimes empty value if entered incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome

There is a crazy thing happening with my input of type=date:

```js
function getValue() {
  $('#entered').text($('input[name=test_date]').val());  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" min="2018-01-01" max="2018-05-05" name="test_date">
<button onclick="getValue()">Get value</button>
<p>Entered: <span id="entered"></span></p>
```

If I enter an invalid value, it will change to a valid value automatically, but not always a true date. The max date is always 31.

Ex:

- Enter: "01/55/2018" => "01/31/2018" -- True
- Enter: "02/55/2018" => "02/31/2018" -- False

And In the case of False, both jQuery or PHP cannot get the value. It always returns `""`.

I want to get value even if it's invalid. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What is your question? What would you like to happen?

Comment: If your date input is incorrect , getting empty is better than incorrect value !! isn't ?

Comment: I using Chrome. I want to get value even if  it's invalid.
In my case, when user enter a invalid date, I need to show error message. But if I cannot get the value, I do not know if the user entered wrong or not enter anything.

Comment: If an input value is invalid, show the error on the client side with client-side scripts/validation. No need to pass it to the server to have the server show the user an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#date-state-(type%3Ddate)) documentation:

> The value attribute, if specified and not empty, must have a value
> that is a valid date string.
>
> The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the
> element is not a valid date string, then set it to the empty string
> instead.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> According to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231811, the reason is simplicity.
>
> If you want to show error message when User enter invalid date. You can validate with input.validity.badInput or validationMessage:
> [image]