# Get value of date input when invalid date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

**In the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duwa0cqm/), if the input is set to an invalid date, such as 2/31/2000, `.val()` returns `""`**

```
<input type="date" id="date-test" />
<div id="date-label"></div>
```

```
$('#date-test').on('change', function() {
    var inputDate = $(this).val();
    $('#date-label').html(inputDate)
});
```

As I have read in the comments, this behavior is by design.

**Question:**

Since I can't check for an empty string, how do I tell when a user has not entered a date vs entering an invalid date?

Comment: what browser are you testing on? on chrome I get this warning `The specified value "31/31/3333" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"`

Comment: Testing in Chrome

Comment: that's  how it suppose to work. Try entering invalid number in a `type="number"` input

Comment: Regarding the "why", see [input date empty if entered incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285254/html5-input-type-date-is-sometimes-empty-value-if-entered-incorrectly).

Comment: Interesting.  So is there a way to access the "incorrect date"?  How do I tell the difference between a user not entering a date and entering an invalid date?

Answer (score 0):

This got me thinking, so I played around a bit, maybe something like this can help or inspire someone for some other idea...

if you type 02/31/2000 you will get what was typed. But there are obvious problems with this.

And to say, you could also obliviously use some date-picker library, that's what they made for. HTML elements like time and date are very limited, and I don't think that will change any time soon.

```js
let keys = [];
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  console.clear();
  keys.push(e.code)
  //console.log(keys)
};

$('#date-test').on('input', function() {
  let keys2 = [];
  keys.forEach(key => {
    let key3 = key.split("Digit")
    keys2.push(key3[1])
  })  
  $('#date-label').html(keys2)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="date-test" />
<div id="date-label"></div>
```